# How can I extract all characters between two delimiters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I got following "string":

```
<form>{% include '../form.html' %}</form>
```

I would now like to extract the "../form.html" out of the import tag with javascript:

```
var regex = /b{\% include | $\%}/i;

var source = "<form>{% include './form.html' %}</form>";

console.log(regex.exec(source));
```

However I actually have no idea what to do ^^. My problems about this are:

- how to handle special characters (e.g. `"{"` and `"%"`)
- how to test if they occur in an line (word boundaries?)
- how to check that the found piece starts AND ends with the tag
- how to extract the string between the `"'"` and `"'"`

**Update**

What about if I have a whole text which has multiple appearances of an include?

```
<form>{% include '../form.html' %}</form>
<table>{% include '../table.html' %}</table>
```

Comment: Really no special regex characters in the context you've used them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special to do:

```
var regex = /{% (?:include|import|extends) '([^']+)' %}/gi;

var source = "<form>{% include './form.html' %}  {% import './form2.html' %}</form>";

var results = [], found;
while (found = regex.exec(source)) {
    results.push(found[1]);
}
console.log(results);
```

Comment: What can I do if I have multiple includes?

Comment: @bodokaiser: like this: `{% include './form1.html' %} {% include './form2.html' %}` or like this: `{% include './form1.html' include './form2.html' %}`? For the first one, you only need to put the g modifier at the end of the pattern (with the "i")

Comment: I am using /\{% (import|include|extends) '([^']+)' %\}/gi but still getting only './form.html' (no table.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\{% include '(.+?)' %\}
```

http://regex101.com/r/nY1aP2

By using the non-greedy `.+?` and capturing it out, your first capture group will include the `./form.html` that you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
s="<form>{% include '../form.html' %}</form>";
re = /\{% +include +(['"])([^'"]+)\1/;
fn = s.match(re)[2]; //=> ../form.html
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like:

```
var text = "<form>{% include '../form.html' %}</form>";
var extractedUrl = /(?:include '(.*?)' %)/.exec(text)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just follow the input pattern, the whole match is in group 0
the part between quotes is group 1.

```
 #   /<form>{%[ \t]+include[ \t]+'([^']+)'[ \t]+%}<\/form>/


 <form>{% [ \t]+ include [ \t]+ 
 '
 ( [^']+ )                          # (1)
 '
 [ \t]+ %}</form>
```